# Select from many to many relations table

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Given these tables:

[image: scenarios-suites tables]

I would like to query scenarios with all the connected suites.

results:

```
 **scenario**         **suites**
loginScenario         loginSignup, endToEnd, smoke
  addToCart           shoppingCart, paymentOptions, endToEnd
```

Please direct me to the preferred postgresql select query

Also the relation here is one (scenario) to many (suites) , if the design should be different please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use joins and string aggegation:

```
select 
    sc.description scenario_description, 
    string_agg(su.description, ', ') all_suites_descriptions
from scenario_suit scsu
inner join scenarios sc on sc.scenario_id = scsu.scenario
inner join suites su    on su.suite_id    = scsu.suite
group by sc.scenario_id
```

I made the assumption that table `suites` has a column called `description`, which you want to display.